# buttons icon are disappearing after clicking in IOS Device

Tags: html, css

I have created a button with a span for text and I have added background-image to span. In Ios devices, when I click on button, background-image disappears.

```
.button {
    width: 210px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #B5D676;
    border: 1px solid #587F54;
    color: #325c46;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: ptsans-bold, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.button span.link {
    background-image: url(../images/icon-link.png);
}

<button type="submit" value="Continue" class="button">
   <span class="link">
      @SharedLocalizer["ContinueText"]
   </span>
</button>
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: So to understand the image shows and then only when clicked it disappears?

Comment: I had problems with IOS background images before, i found that `background-attachment:initial; background-size: cover;` helped overcome it, so maybe try this on `.button span.link` and see if it stays, but could be css like `:active` on the button that overwrites your background image.

Comment: @Ylama Yes, on clicking image disappears in ios devices only.

Comment: @Ylama on setting background-size, my button design changes. image covers the text.

Comment: try `background-size: auto;` then  maybe but play around with it , inspect browser `HTML`  on IOS device and look at the `css` should show you why its not showing or being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I create a codepen but it still work

I added 
`background-size: 100%` to see all image

See the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjVbqQ

Comment: background size 100% will change my button design.

Comment: @Sonali I remove `background-size: 100%` but it still work. Are you able to create fiddle or codepen?